# Creating Positive Images in Python with Open CV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, haar-classifier

I am fairly new to coding, but I have been doing a lot of research. I have been trying to make my own haar cascade using python and open cv. I have all of my negative samples and a few pictures for my positive ones. I was hoping to run a create_samples command with cv2 but can't find anything for how to do it on windows (only linux, which I tried but my digital oceans server wasn't working). If you have any experience or know of any resources please send them my way.

Basically what I need to do is impose my positive images onto my negatives ones with a tilt angle to create a lot of samples.

Answer (score 0):

You Don't Need OpenCV for image Creation. This is how you can create an image from a 2D array.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
#gradient between 0 and 1 for 256*256 1d arrray
array = np.linspace(0,1,256*256)
#reshape to 2d
mat = np.reshape(array,(256,256))
#creates PIL image
img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(mat*255) , 'L')
img.show()
```

this code will give you your deserved custom image.
Thank You